# Show only a few markers in plotly express

Tags: python, plotly, marker

I am doing a plot with [Plotly's line](https://plotly.com/python/line-charts/). My lines are "high resolution" in the sense that they have many points. I want to add one category using the `symbol` parameter like in [the example here](https://plotly.com/python/line-charts/#line-charts-with-markers). That example works fine when there are few points, but because it adds one marker per point when the line is too dense it fails

This is an example of one of my plots without the `symbol` argument

[image]

and this is how it looks after I use `symbol`:

[image]

Some of the symbols are crosses and some are dots, of course this cannot be seen because of the high density of points. One solution would be to drop a fraction of points prior to doing the plot, but that would reduce the resolution of my traces.

Is it possible to tell Plotly to show only a fraction of the markers?

Comment: try reducing `size` of markers & use different `markers`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately that is not an option because they become so small that you cannot see them. The only solution I see is to draw only a fraction of the markers.

Answer (score 1):

- Have create some lines with 10k observations
- you can sample these lines and add additional traces that carry the markers.  In this case have chosen every 1000
- marker symbols - have used different ones selected from list of valid ones

*updated based on comments* Define how many markers you want rather than at fixed step size.

```
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np
import random
from plotly.validators.scatter.marker import SymbolValidator

x = np.linspace(50, 100, random.randint(5*10**4, 3*10**5))
fig = px.line(
    x=x, y=[np.vectorize(lambda x: (x / f) ** f)(x) for f in np.linspace(2, 2.7, 6)]
)

# 21 markers, n+1 because of 0th
marker_step = len(fig.data[0].x) // 20

for t, s in zip(
    fig.data,
    [
        s
        for s in SymbolValidator().values[2::3]
        if len(s) < 3 or not (s[-3:] == "dot" or s[-3:] == "pen")
    ],
):
    fig.add_traces(
        go.Scattergl(
            x=t.x[::marker_step],
            y=t.y[::marker_step],
            mode="markers",
            marker_color=t.line.color,
            marker_symbol=s,
            marker_size=10,
            showlegend=False,
        )
    )

fig
```

[image]

Comment: This is what I am looking for, but with the interface of plotly express. I guess it is not possible, right?

Comment: The reason I used **go** to create additional traces was to ensure that **Scattergl** was used and **px** did not default to **Scatter** for performance reasons.  There is not a feature in **plotly** to show markers every *n* points in a trace.  Hence reason I provided a pretty generic solution using additional traces

Comment: Okay, but suppose that instead of 10000 points you have just 100 per line, that's enough for my problem to appear. Could you have done this with plotly express? Maybe with some call to `update_traces` and some property after the plot was generated?

Comment: you can't, **mode** is *lines* or *lines+markers* later will display marker for every co-ordinate.   No way to define subset of co-ordinates that have markers within a trace.   I'll update answer to demonstrate it's utility

Comment: updated answer so define number of markers rather than step between markers.   functionally exactly the same, just calc step.   also made **numpy** array size random and bigger